# How to implement Android preference with a second screen description?

Tags: android, android-preferences

On the Android design guideline there's this line:
[image: android settings design guideline]
which is the same as how the WiFi setting work in the Settings app.

I can implement this with a regular preference and a custom second screen, but i suppose there is a easier way?

Comment: you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html for this

Comment: Yes, but the second screen will still look nothing like the one in the example, after some digging into the source of the settings app, it seems it is implemented with a "SwitchBar": https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/layout/settings_main_prefs.xml

Comment: in this question you asked about a "second screen" not about the "on/off? switchable preference

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it very clear. I was hoping there's a simple option to turn a regular SwitchPreference into a styled second screen.

Comment: this is what you can achieve with PreferenceScreen. Actually you can design it as you wish. You can add any preferences into the 2nd screen